# Fresnel and blend option not showing in transparency panel

Tags: materials, transparency, blend-modes

I'm creating a material for which I need to edit fresnel and blend options in the transparency panel and I don't have it.
What am I missing (blender v2.79) ?

[image]

Comment: Are you in the right renderer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Render your 3d image and then try

Comment: Thanks. I was not in the right engine (blender game instead of blender render)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this same problem.

The way I fixed this is by selecting all my strips and making them a "metastrip" (right click, select "`Make Meta Strip`" OR click `"Command" G`).

This then saves you the time of rendering first, which can be quite time consuming when you are dealing with big video files.